# the selected time in the spinner by connecting the adapter to the recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

i am new to kotlin. i want to make an app where user can share by selecting timer on spinner and pressing button but i have problem showing countdown timer.can you help me to connect countdown timer to adapter

my adapter

```
        class kampanyaadapter(
        val kampanyalistesi:ArrayList<kampanya>, private val onItemClickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?,
    ):RecyclerView.Adapter<kampanyaadapter.paylasimholder>()

 {

private lateinit var mListener:onItemClickListenerr

interface onItemClickListenerr{
    fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}

fun setOnClickListener(listener:onItemClickListenerr){
    mListener=listener
}


class paylasimholder(itemView: View,listener:onItemClickListenerr):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var timeStamp: TextView

    init {
        timeStamp=itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp)
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)

        }

    }





  

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): paylasimholder {
    val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row,parent,false)
    return paylasimholder(view,mListener)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: paylasimholder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.recycler_row_kullaniciadi.text=kampanyalistesi[position].kullaniciadi
    holder.itemView.recycler_row_aciklama.text=kampanyalistesi[position].aciklama




    holder.bind(onItemClickListener)



    if (kampanyalistesi[position].downloadurl!=null){
        holder.itemView.recycler_row_imageview.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        Picasso.get().load(kampanyalistesi[position].downloadurl).into(holder.itemView.recycler_row_imageview)
    }






}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return kampanyalistesi.size

}
```

}

my activity

the timer here should be shown in the recycling view when the button is pressed(fun paylasim yap)

```
class kampanyaolustur  : AppCompatActivity() , AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
var secilengorsel: Uri? = null
var secilenbitmap: Bitmap? = null

var countDownTimers: Array<CountDownTimer?>?=null
private lateinit var kampanyaadapterr: kampanyaadapter



var button: Button? = null
var spinner: Spinner? = null
var textView: TextView? = null
var item: String? = null
var member: Member? = null
var sureler = arrayOf<String?>("Choose time", "yarim saat", "1 saat", "3 saat")



private lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage
private lateinit var database: FirebaseFirestore
val db = Firebase.firestore

private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kampanyaolustur)



    auth = Firebase.auth
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2)
    button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_id)
    spinner?.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
    member = Member()
    val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*> =
        ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sureler)
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner?.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
  //  button?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { SaveValue(item) })



}

override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, i: Int, l: Long) {
    item = spinner!!.selectedItem.toString()

    textView!!.text = item
}

override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?) {}


fun SaveValue(item: String?) {
    if (item == "Choose time") {
        Toast.makeText(this, "süre seçiniz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else if(item=="yarim saat") {
        countDownTimers = arrayOf(object : CountDownTimer(1800000, 1000) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                var diff = millisUntilFinished
                val secondsInMilli: Long = 1000
                val minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60
                val hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60


                val elapsedHours = diff / hoursInMilli
                diff %= hoursInMilli

                val elapsedMinutes = diff / minutesInMilli
                diff %= minutesInMilli

                val elapsedSeconds = diff / secondsInMilli

                textView2.text = "$elapsedHours saat $elapsedMinutes dakika $elapsedSeconds saniye"

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                textView2.text = "kampanya süresi doldu!"
            }

        }.start())

        Toast.makeText(this, "süre alındı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}








fun paylasimyap(view: View) {
  
    SaveValue(item)








            }



        }else{
            veritabaninakaydet(null)




        }

    }
```

}

other activity

```
class anasayfa : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

val db=Firebase.firestore
var kampanyalistesi=ArrayList<kampanya>()
private lateinit var recyclerviewadapter:kampanyaadapter
private lateinit var countDownTimer:CountDownTimer
var onItemClickListener:AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?=null
val onItemClick:AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?=null
var countDownTimers: Array<CountDownTimer?>?=null


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val menuInflater=menuInflater
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)









    val layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager=layoutManager
    recyclerviewadapter= kampanyaadapter(kampanyalistesi,onItemClickListener,countDownTimers)
    recyclerView.adapter=recyclerviewadapter
    recyclerviewadapter.setOnClickListener(object :kampanyaadapter.onItemClickListenerr{
        override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {

            val intent= Intent(applicationContext, profil::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    })







}

                    }
                    recyclerviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500** (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited the codes as best I could.